# What does it mean to run a virtual OS in "headless mode"?

Tags: vmware, virtualization

I've been hearing a lot about about how the new version of VMWare Fusion can run virtual operating systems in "headless mode".

A Google search makes it clear that other virtualisation products also have similar features, however, I have not been able to find a good description of what this actually means? What is happening when you do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Headless mode means that the virtual machine is running in the background without any foreground elements visible (like the Vmware Fusion application)
You would have no screen to see running the front end; i.e. the screen/console would not be visible, even though the operating system is running, and would typically have to access the machine via SSH.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that is interested, you can activate headless mode in VMWare Fusion by running the following command in Terminal.app

```
defaults write com.vmware.fusion fluxCapacitor -bool YES
```

Comment: I believe that command only works in VMWare Fusion 2. For version 3, see http://superuser.com/questions/131800/fusion-create-headless-virtual-machines/

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve the same on Parallels?