# Headless mode in Parallels?

Tags: headless, parallels

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171948/what-does-it-mean-to-run-a-virtual-os-in-headless-mode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297088/starting-vmware-in-headless-mode). And since I'm a Parallels user,(upgraded to v11 Pro recently) wanted to know that if it is possible to run a Virtual Machine in Parallels in headless mode.

Comment: The other answer is almost right. Still, the perfect description is [here](http://kb.parallels.com/123298).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work.
Actually when you disconnect monitor from Mac Pro or Mac Mini the display system reconfigured with software display. But this displays is not uses OpenGL acceleration. It is means that Windows Server reads framebuffer pixels to memory.
But VM can use hardware acceleration of graphics adapter for offline rendering.